# Should I be using the jQuery .ready() function?

Tags: jquery

A contractor wrote the below code for an application I'm now supporting. It appears in the head tags of the login page, after my other scripts are loaded, and is working fine. I'm hoping someone can explain:

1) Is there an advantage to coding it this way rather than using .ready()

2) Would it be better to use .ready() instead of declaring an anonymous function. (that is an anonymous function, correct?)

3) Is it possible that this code could execute before the DOM it's trying to reference is available or is jQuery preventing this somehow?

I'm using jQuery 1.9.0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    try {
        console.log( "login_panel.init" );
        // If no userid has been obtained from the user's cookies...
        var $userid = $( "#userid" );
        if ( '' == $userid.val() ) {
            // focus the user ID field.
            $userid.focus();
        } else {
            // The user ID has been autofilled so focus the password field.
            $( "#pwd" ).focus();
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.log( e.message );
    }
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually shorthand for $(document).ready();

You're okay

Here is the documentation on .ready();

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

`$(function() {` is just the other way of writing `$(document).ready(function(){})`

these are all same :

- `$(document).ready(handler)`
- `$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)`
- `$(handler)`

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

You already are, `$(function() { .. })` is a shortcut for document ready.

The try / catch and the Yoda condition is however really uneccessary. All you need is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        if ( $( "#userid" ).val() == '' ) {
            $( "#userid" ).focus();
        }else{
            $( "#pwd" ).focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Is there an advantage to coding it this way rather than using .ready()

**The advantage is its easier to understand for newbies of jQuery. And is more readable.**

2) Would it be better to use .ready() instead of declaring an anonymous function. (that is an anonymous function, correct?)

**Refer above answer**

3) Is it possible that this code could execute before the DOM it's trying to reference is available or is jQuery preventing this somehow?

**It is possible. But for that you have to put the javascript code after the tags that are used in the script and this time you don't have to enclose it in a function. But this is a very bad practice. You should use this syntax or document ready. You know? the best practice is to use all the scripts after all the tags are ended but just before finishing `</body>` tag. But of course with this syntax or document ready**

Comment: 3) is wrong, when using a DOM ready event, the DOM is ready, that's why we use it after all. And it's not bad practice to include javascript at the end of the document, right before the closing body tag, quite the opposite ?

Comment: please read my post carefully. I think you have mistaken what I have said

Comment: You know? the best practice is to use all the scripts after all the tags are ended but just before finishing body tag

Comment: sorry the body tag got hidden by SO

Answer (score 1):

shorthand for `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready
```

is the event that occurs when the dom is completed rendering.